# Correcting json format and implementing in Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a json file with the lines of format:

```
{"user1" : "a",
"mobile": "b",
"address": "c"

{"user2" : "aa",
"mobile": "bb",
"address": "cc"
```

This log is incorrect as there is no `}` towards the end of each line

I tried

```
text_file = open('abc.txt', "r",  encoding='utf-8')
read = text_file.read()
a = read.split("\n")
for i in a:
    print(i+"}")
```

This is giving me one extra `}` towards the end of all the lines.How can I avoid it?

Also, I need to implement the same logic in spark. Please let me know what modification are required or if there is much better logic in spark

Comment: You have to use the built-in `json` module to validate your string and then correct it based on what error is shown. There isn't any magic utility that I know of which will fix your string.

Comment: example of what its your current script returns would help? it is printing }} at the end of each line?

Comment: It is printing {"user1" : "a", "mobile": "b", "address": "c"}
{"user2" : "aa", "mobile": "bb", "address": "cc"}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**with Python**

```
text_file = open('abc.txt', 'r')
read = text_file.read()
a = read.split('{') # split with '{'
del a[0] # remove the first line contains space
for i in a:
    print("{"+i.strip()+"}") # if you want to remove '\n' add .replace('\n','')
```

result :

```
{"user1" : "a",
"mobile": "b",
"address": "c"}
{"user2" : "aa",
"mobile": "bb",
"address": "cc"}
```

**with Spark**

```
# use wholeTextFiles to read all lines, textFile split lines with '\n'    
text_file = sc.wholeTextFiles("abc.txt") 
a = text_file.map(lambda (pathFile , lines) : lines). # select only lines
               flatMap(lambda text : text.split('{')). # split with '{'
               filter(lambda line : len(line) > 0). # remove the first line
               map(lambda line : '{'+line.strip()+'}') 
for i in a.collect() :
    print i
```

result :

```
{"user1" : "a",
"mobile": "b",
"address": "c"}
{"user2" : "aa",
"mobile": "bb",
"address": "cc"}
```